# iOS - Global exception handler

Tags: iphone, ios, exception, crash, crash-reports

Is there anyway to implement a global exception handler for iPhone apps such that exceptions, instead of silently crashing the app, could allow for some sort of message?

I can understand if it's not do-able since the program may be in an inconsistent state, but it'd be nice to at least tell users "Sorry - something went wrong!"

Thanks!

Comment: Did you got any way to display alert message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you implement global iPhone Exception Handling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282364/how-do-you-implement-global-iphone-exception-handling)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282364/iphone-exception-handling) for the answer. It seems to indicate that you'll be getting junky stack traces, but you definitely can set a global exception handler. Good luck!

Comment: Sam to the rescue again! Thanks Sam!