# How to handle all the exceptions in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception

Is there anyway in ios to handle all the exceptions that occurred in entire application in a single try catch block.

If yes where should I write this block.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You have to create code which will work well:) You can analyze crash log for looking for all critical exeptions to fix their. The are useful services for getting crashes(e.g Crashlytics).

Comment: I would also ask yourself "why are you handling unhandled exceptions?" The better solution might be to make sure of an object and its state before trying to use that object. I am not a fan of Try/Catch unless you are dealing with some third party library of which you have no control. For things you do have control of (your code), Try/Catch should be questioned whenever used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` to set the handler.

Swift:

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { (exception) in
    while true {
        sleep(UInt32(0.5))
    }
}
```

Objective-C:

```
void handleException(NSException* exception) {
    while true {
        sleep(0.5);
    }
}

NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(handleException);
```

When the handler is returned, the app crashes and Xcode shows the error. So you can run a loop until you want to quit the app. I do not recommend to keep the app running normally, but you can show for example an alert saying an error occurred and when the user taps a button, the app crashes. Use a flag for the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is about Objective-C there is no need to handle exceptions because they are not to be used for program control. Exceptions are only to be used to catch non-recoverable programming errors so if you get one the code needs to be fixed.

In general exceptions across stack frames are not handled in a manner that is recoverable.

The best thing to do is add an exception breakpoint in Xcode so you can better examine exceptions:

From the Mian Menu Debug:Breakpoints:Create Exception Breakpoint. Run the app to get the breakpoint. When you hit the exception breakpoint **click debug continue** a couple of times and you will get a backtrace and more error info. Add that and an exact copy of Xcode/Debugger messages to the question.

It is also a good idea to change this breakpoint to "Objective-C only."

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look into the concept of handling exceptions globally in iOS. I might not be able to give the most correct answer but these links can spread some more light on what you might just want.

[iOS Global Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282364/how-do-you-implement-global-iphone-exception-handling)

[Global Exception Handler in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341457/ios-global-exception-handler)

Hope this helps.

Comment: In Objetive-C exceptions can not reliably be recovered from and can not successfully be used for program control. They are only to be used to catch non-recoverable programming errors.

Comment: Of Course yes, they provide more complex stack traces and messages, but if you need a top level Exception handler, there might not be any other options available, excuding what OP asked, because that is something not available into iOS scope.

Comment: Objective-C does not clean-up the objects that are on the stack on exceptions, this includes strongly retained objects.