# Can I crash my app by myself?

Tags: ios, uibutton

iOS APP question

I have a special case that I want There is a Button , and when it `onClicked`,the APP will crash itself (on control)

**Example**

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(noThisMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

it's simply work ...『crash』 after this added in Code.

but....Will this app approve by apple? or will reject by apple?

if this will be reject by apple,is there any document maintained it?

Thanks for your great help!

Comment: No, apple wont approve it. Why do you want to crash an app in first place? https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/142194/ios-6-problem---application-rejected-from-app-store

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to exit iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting App Store Review Guidelines Section 2:

> **2.1** Apps that crash will be rejected

Furthermore -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491688/1155387

Answer (score 1):

If they catch the crash then no they won't approve it.

If they miss it and don't get it to crash themselves then yes they will approve it.

Comment: But if My Button is named Stop APP?

Comment: You should never ever have a button like that, why would you even want a stop app button.

Comment: @BirdHsuie, You are not supposed stop the app like that. Mostly the user will delete the app if they see these crashes. Home button is there for minimizing the app and you can disable multitasking to make homebutton close the app.

Comment: You should not have a "stop app" button. If you put a "stop app" button in then Apple will almost certainly reject the app. In fact, the guidelines say that you should not have an "exit" or "close" button in the app. You have to deal with the Home button being pressed properly.

Comment: But I didn't see the document mention that@@!!

Comment: like Borrrden said... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491466/call-exit0-in-iphone-app/8491688#8491688

Comment: As mentioned by @Fogmeister here is the link to the apple HIG: [Don’t Quit Programmatically](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27)