# Killing an iOS app programmatically

Tags: ios, exit, terminate

I have an app when a specific action fires I close the app and ask the user to reopen it again.

The problem is when the app executes `exit(0)` the app stays in the apps stack (when I click the home button twice). I want it to be killed completely so that `viewDidLoad()` will be executed again when the app opens.

Comment: Why? There should be absolutely no need to do that.

Comment: I need it in my code.

Comment: No, you need to program the app in way it does not need a manual restart.

Comment: Just because the app is listed in the recent applications list doesn't mean it is running, but as others pointed out, calling `exit` is against apple's guidelines.

Comment: Okay then what are the alternatives to reload the app when the user open it again ? I want ViewDidLoad to be executed again

Comment: no, you do not, there is no reason for that, put any custom logic you have in viewDidLoad into some other function and call that function.

Comment: So what if it's against Apple guidelines? The question is not whether it is, or it is not. There are some legitimate uses for that, especially for internal and testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot terminate an app on it's own.

From Apple's Human User Guidelines...

> ## Don’t Quit Programmatically
>
> Never quit an iOS application programmatically because people tend to
> interpret this as a crash. However, if external circumstances prevent
> your application from functioning as intended, you need to tell your
> users about the situation and explain what they can do about it.
> Depending on how severe the application malfunction is, you have two
> choices.
>
> Display an attractive screen that describes the problem and suggests a
> correction. A screen provides feedback that reassures users that
> there’s nothing wrong with your application. It puts users in control,
> letting them decide whether they want to take corrective action and
> continue using your application or press the Home button and open a
> different application
>
> If only some of your application's features are not working, display
> either a screen or an alert when people activate the feature. Display
> the alert only when people try to access the feature that isn’t
> functioning.

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491688/742298

Comment: Okay then what are the alternatives to reload the app when the user open it again ? I want ViewDidLoad to be executed again

Comment: put your portion of code into separate method which needed to be re-executed. call that function from viewDidLoad and also call from the code where you wanted to quit your application.