# Want to kill iOS App while in suspended state

Tags: ios, swift4, swift5, xcode11, background-fetch

I want to kill my application if it is in the suspended mode for more than 30mins so that when it relaunches it fetches new data. I have looked all over but wasn't able to find a solution to it. If anyone can recommend something it will be a huge help.

```
exit(0)
```

This above command is not recommended and apple will reject the application. Then there is the functionality of `BGAppRefreshTask` for iOS13 and above or `minimumBackgroundFetchInterval` for iOS less than iOS13, but still how to actually kill the application programmatically? Any help would be such a plus. Thanks

Comment: I do recommend that instead you should aim at some kind of app state relaunch without resorting to killing the process if the right conditions are met.

Comment: @Kamil.S Erm, I dont quite understand what you're saying.. umm can u suggest how?

Comment: Obviously I don't know what your app exactly does. But very vaguely - detect the condition upon foregrounding the app and if it's met do the steps the app would normally do upon a cold launch. Additionally reset the screen navigation stack and do whatever you do for fetching data to make the app state fully functional again.

Comment: Oh that i know ofcourse, I just thought theres a way of actually killing the app starting afresh.. however what you're suggesting is that whenever the app is suspended, i kick off with a timer, e.g. if the timer has gone till 20mins, i reset the rootviewcontroller to the initialviewcontroller and re fetch the data.. hmm thats kind of doable as well.. however what do you think about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52515554/3359372

Comment: You'd have to measure time upon backgrounding and foregrounding and calculate at the difference as `dispatchAfter` won't give you the result you expect while app is in background. If you don't care about user setting date manually on the device in between you can use `Date`. To be extra secure you can rely instead on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203662/getting-system-uptime-in-ios-swift