# How to get detailed iOS exception messages

Tags: ios, exception

How do I get detailed iOS exception descriptions as seen below (I've seen several people refer to such descriptions):

CALayer position contains NaN: [2.74665e-34 nan]
2012-04-05 15:48:00.185 Infectious[28198:fb03] (

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0226803e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02820cd6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x02210a48 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] 
3   CoreFoundation                      0x022109b9 +[NSException raise:format:] + 57
4   QuartzCore                          0x00df3c0d _ZN2CA5Layer12set_positionERKNS
5   QuartzCore                          0x00de9f55 -[CALayer setPosition:] + 68
6   QuartzCore                          0x00de9a0a -[CALayer setFrame:] + 675
7   UIKit                               0x00efbfb8 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 198
8   UIKit                               0x010071a1 -[UILabel setFrame:] + 233
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Add an exception breakpoint in xcode, and/or use a custom exceptionhandler.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

And

[How do you implement global iPhone Exception Handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282364/how-do-you-implement-global-iphone-exception-handling)