# iOS Recover app on crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my first time that I'm running app on my device. I was wondering what to do when app crashes. When it crashes, I can not open the app again, the app data is corrupted I think. Do I need to write some code for this scenario? When app crashes I want to be able to open my app again. I was using simulator till now and this is my first time on my device. I was searching but could not found how to recover my app

Comment: No you cannot reopen it again and the only solution is to fix the bugs that are causing the crash.

Answer (score 1):

You can recover from almost anything if you handle exceptions AND signals

BUT you should't:

crashes shouldn't happen and if you get a unix signal you shouldn't try to recover because after a near-crash the app may be in a quite undefined state

---

**localize & fix & prevent the crash**

Answer (score 0):

Localize the source of the crash, add checks to prevent the crash. You can also set a [global exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282364/how-do-you-implement-global-iphone-exception-handling) to help you debugging the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem; and found a library that handles hardware exceptions that xcode can not. the library name called [SignalRecovery](https://github.com/dhatbj/SignalRecovery);
you will find an error using the library in sizeof function that should take a struct.